# how to add error catching to this tokenization function

Tags: python, indexing, tokenize

I am trying to use split() to look for hashtags and users in tweets.

Here is an example of a tweet I am trying to pull information out of

`One version of a layout I never put live. This was from sometime in  January. http://t.co/PppHGmRa`

I am using this code:

```
def get_tweet_meta(tweet_text, tweet_id, auth):
     api = auth
     words = tweet_text.split(" ")
     hashtags = []
     at_user = []
     meta = {}
     print tweet_text
     for word in words:
         print word
         print word[0]
         if word[0] is '#':
             hashtags.append(word)
         if word[0] is '@':
             at_user.append(word)

      print hashtags
      print at_user
```

I get to the `in` in the tweet and I am getting an error I think is to do with extra     whitespace.

```
in
i

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitterBot3.py", line 111, in <module>
    get_tweet_meta(value, key, auth)
  File "twitterBot3.py", line 86, in get_tweet_meta
    print word[0]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The code works with a normalized text block but is throwing errors here, any ideas. Thanks

Comment: Never use `is` to test for string equality. Use `==` instead.

Comment: changed but still throwing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splitting on single spaces; this can lead to empty results anywhere there is more than one space in a row.

Use `str.split()` **without** an argument to split on arbitrary whitespace and strip starting and ending whitespace:

```
>>> s = ' spaces  in odd    places  '
>>> s.split(' ')
['', 'spaces', '', 'in', 'odd', '', '', '', 'places', '', '']
>>> s.split()
['spaces', 'in', 'odd', 'places']
```

`word[0]` on an empty string then raises an `IndexError`.

You should never use `is` to test for equality; use `==` for that. `is` tests for object identity. Any string or integer this actually works with is a special case where the interpreter implementation has opted to optimise some aspect (memory, dictionary access, etc.) by reusing objects internally.

Comment: @KyleSponable if the answer solved your question please accept it by clicking on the "V" on the top-left corner of the answer. Thanks.